# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'className') at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror, this

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lh3wH.png)  I am new to javascript. I am trying to switch between the sections and I am getting a TypeError.
Don't know what to do.

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const sectBtns  = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');  
const sectBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.control');     
const allSections = document.querySelector('.main-content');  


function PageTransition() {
    //Button click active class
    for(let i = 0; i < sectBtn.length; i++) {
        sectBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            let currentBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.active-btn');
           
            currentBtn[0].className = 
            currentBtn[0].className.replace('active-btn', '');

            this.className += 'active-btn';
        })
    }
}
```

And here's my HTML code. I have element with the class name active-btn.

```
<body class="main-content">
    <header class="section sec1 header active">

    </header>    

    <main>
        <section class="section sec2 about"></section>
        <section class="section sec3 portfolio"></section>
        <section class="section sec4 skills"></section>
        <section class="section sec5 contact"></section>
    </main>
    
    <div class="contorls">
        <div class="control control-1 active-btn">
            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="control control-2" data-id="about">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="control control-3" data-id="portfolio">
            <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="control control-4" data-id="skills">
            <i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="control control-5" data-id="contact">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope-open"></i>
        </div>
           
    </div>

<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: please add your html code here too

Comment: There's no elements with class `active-btn` in the document. Also, take a look at [ClassList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: Hi @ZainShabir, I have updated the code. Can you please review it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        currentBtn[0].className = 
        currentBtn[0].className.replace('active-btn', '');

        this.className += 'active-btn';
```

I was having the same problem.
Here, when you are changing the classname. Instead of `this.className += "active-btn"` it should be `this.className += " active-btn"` with a space at the beginning of the class name "active-btn". If no space will be used the class name will be concatenated to the other class name.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you try to get the active button, there aren't any elements with that class, so `document.querySelectorAll` just returns an empty array.

Then, when you try to access the first element, that returns `undefined`.

What causes the error is trying to access `className` on that `undefined`.

You can fix that by using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), so it only accesses the property if there's an element.

```js
for(let i = 0; i < sectBtn.length; i++) {
    sectBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        //                       (1)
        let currentBtn = document.querySelector('.active-btn');

        //        (2)    (3)  (4)
        currentBtn?.classList.remove('active-btn');

        this.classList.add('active-btn')
    })
}
```

1. I changed this to `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll` because you are only looking for the first result.
2. This is the optional chaining. If `currentBtn` is `null` or `undefined`, then nothing will happen (no error).

   If it isn't `null` or `undefined`, then the `active-btn` class will be removed.
3. This is changed to `classList` instead of `className`, because `classList` has a better API.
4. This is how you remove a class with `classList`. If you want to read more about it, this is the [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove).

I hope this helps! :)